# Failed test in jenkins maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

i have a problem with maven in jenkins. When I building application using maven in jenkis, I got error:

```
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   MessageResourceIT.Should add Message to Room:49 Condition not satisfied:

response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED
|        |               |             |
|        403 FORBIDDEN   false         201 CREATED
```

It looks like a normal failed test, but when I building application in my computer, test is correct.

My test:

```
def "Should add Message to Room"() {
    given:
        Room room = roomHelper.room()
        participantHelper.participant(room.id, user.id)
        AddMessageRequest request = messageHelper.addMessageRequest()
        String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath('/room/{roomId}/message')
                .buildAndExpand(room.id)
        HttpEntity payload = new HttpEntity<>(request, userHeaders)
    when:
        ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, payload, MessageResponse.class)
    then:
        response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED
        response.body
        MessageResponse messageResponse = response.body
        messageResponse.content == request.content
}
```

my setup:

```
def setup() {
    String userLogin = 'test'
    String userPassword = 'test'
    user = userHelper.user(userPassword, userLogin)
    userHeaders = securityHelper.securityHeader(userLogin, userPassword)
}
```

It's look as jenkins running tests asynchronously and another test removed users when this test is running.

I using maven-failsafe-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <includes>
            <include>%regex[.*IT.*]</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Anyone have an idea what can happen and how to fix it?

Comment: First the includes configuration in maven-failsafe-plugin can remove cause it's default furthermore on which URL you are trying to access? Apart from that does your build and test work on your local machine ?

Comment: It's controller on my application, this is an integration test. the problem is that I do not have the user I created recently. Just as if another thread removed it.

Comment: Can I force synchronic tests in jenkins?